# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: sql-server, ssl

While i was logged in SQL server following error was occurred :

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (Provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The specified data could not be decrypted.) (Microsoft SQL Server)

Comment: So...what's your question?

Comment: How to solve and get successfully login in database engine